# Not able to get Excel Saved File path using ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, excel, process

I am not able to get stored full Excel File file path like `"D:\test.xlsx"` using the following code whereas the following code works fine for other file types like docx, txt, ppt. I want to save the file path not the executable path.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string psFilename = ActiveFileName();
    MessageBox.Show(psFilename);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Interval = 20 * 1000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private static string ActiveFileName()
{
    try
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint procId = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out procId);
        //var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById((int)procId);
        //if (proc != null)
        //{
        //    if (proc.Modules[0] != null)
        //    {
        return (GetMainModuleFilepath((int)(procId)));
        //    }
        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString() + " first";
    }
    return string.Empty;

}
public static string GetMainModuleFilepath(int processId)
{
    try
    {
        string wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        {
            using (var results = searcher.Get())
            {
                ManagementObject mo = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (mo != null)
                {
                    return (string)mo["CommandLine"];
                }
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Process testProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Can somebody let me know if any other parameter is needed in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem of not getting excel saved file path. I have used [handle.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) with following code and I was able to get the file path.

```
private static string GetExcelFileName(string pid)
    {
        string actualPath = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Process tool = new Process();
            tool.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PrinterPlusPlus\handle.exe";
            tool.StartInfo.Arguments = "/accepteula -p " + pid;
            tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            tool.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            tool.Start();
            string outputTool = tool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
            string[] lines = outputTool.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                if (s.Contains(".xlsx") && !s.Contains("$"))
                {
                    string[] arrPath = s.Split(new string[] { "File" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    string path = string.Empty;
                    if (arrPath.Length > 1)
                    {
                        actualPath = arrPath[1].Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return actualPath;
    }
```